# Create a Word document with C#?

Tags: c#, reference, ms-word

I'm trying to create a Word document with C# in visual studio 2008, this is my code:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
oWord.Visible = true;
```

Visual studio shows me the error:

> Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Why does this happen?

Comment: On which line? Paste ALL of your code...

Comment: In the line oWord.Visible = true;

Comment: I ask again - paste ALL of your code. Every line in that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code must be inside a method, not in your class definition outside of the methods.

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like this:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;


namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
            oWord.Visible = true;
        }


    }
}
```